# Does Airbus provide pitch control correction symbols outside "normal law"?

Tags: safety

Do pitch control correction symbols exist in 'alternate law' and in 'direct law' mode (if planes angle of attack exceeds dangerously)?

Comment: IIRC they are drawn in amber indicating that the corresponding protection is not available (in alternate law only some protections become unavailable, depending on the reason to enter alternate law), but I would have to look it up to be sure.

Comment: By "pitch control correction symbols" are you talking about the flight director indicators?

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing the operation of the autopilot, the envelope protections and the flight director.

AIUI, the job of the flight director is to indicate the required roll angle and pitch to achieve a new compass heading and/or new altitude that the pilot has selected on the FD. If the AP is engaged, the FD will cause the AP to make the appropriate control movements, otherwise the pilot has to make the control inputs suggested on the FD display.

This has nothing to do with flight envelope protections AFAIK.

In Alternate Law the Flight Director can still be visible.

The BEA identified misuse of the FD as a possible factor in the loss of AF447

---

> *as the flight control law switched from normal to alternate, the flight director’s crossbars disappeared. But they then reappeared several times. ... PF may have trusted the flight director so much that he was verbally agreeing to the other pilot’s pitch-down instructions, while still actually pitching up.*

[AIN online](http://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/2012-07-08/final-af447-report-suggests-pilot-slavishly-followed-flight-director-pitch-commands)

---

> Disconnection of the flight director is normally part of the "unreliable airspeed" procedure. But after the A330 lost its airspeed information, and the autopilot and autothrust automatically disconnected, the crew left the flight directors engaged.

[FlightGlobal](http://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/airbus-reviews-instrument-logic-in-aftermath-of-af447-374484/)